# Decompress a stream of bytes using deflatestream

Tags: c#, c++, deflatestream

I have a server and a client connecting using TCP socket. At the client (which is written in C++) I compress a string (str) using the **zlib** library:

```
uLongf compressedStringLength = compressBound(str.length());
Bytef* compressedString = new Bytef[compressedStringLength];
const Bytef* originalString = reinterpret_cast<const Bytef*>(str.c_str());
compress(compressedString, &compressedStringLength, originalString, str.length());
```

Then I send it to the server. This is the line of code where I write the compressed string to the socket:

```
int bytesWritten = write(sockfd, &compressedString, compressedStringLength);
```

At the server (which is written in C#) I recieve the stream of the compressed bytes from the socket and decompress it using the DeflateStream class:

```
NetworkStream stream = getStream(ref server); //server is a TcpListener object which is initialized to null.
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, size);
Stream decompressedStream = Decompress(bytes);
```

This is the Decompress function:

```
private static Stream Decompress(byte[] input)
{
        var output = new MemoryStream();

        using (var compressStream = new MemoryStream(input))
        using (var decompressor = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            decompressor.CopyTo(output);
        }

        output.Position = 0;
        return output;
 }
```

The compressing process and sending the compressed bytes over the socket works, but I get an exception at the line `decompressor.CopyTo(output);` at the Decompress function above: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Block length does not match with its complement.

Does someone know what the problem is and how can I solve it?

**EDIT**: I`ve already tried to skip the first two bytes brfore the start of the decompression process.

Comment: Have you seen these two SO posts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540125/deflatestream-doesnt-work-on-memorystream, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165884/deflatestream-copyto-writes-nothing-and-throws-no-exceptions

They may help at least with some idea of how to do this.

Comment: Where does `size` come from?

Comment: Could be an endianness error.

Comment: `size` is the size in bytes of the decompressed string. I send it from the client along with the compressed string.

Comment: You're using it as if it was the size of the compressed string.

Comment: See also [.Net zlib inflate with .Net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17212964), [Cannot decompress ZLIB/DEFLATE data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6200395), [Decoding git objects / “Block length does not match with its complement” error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8354811), [Good zlib implementation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513234), and [zlib compressing byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6282575) (to name a few of the many other related posts on Stack Overflow)

Comment: I`ve managed to **solve this issue**. The problem was that at the line of code where I write the compressed string to the socket: `int bytesWritten = write(sockfd, &compressedString, compressedStringLength);`                                 instead of writing the compressed data itself I write the address of `compressedString` which is define as a pointer: `Bytef* compressedString = new Bytef[compressedStringLength];`                   Many thanks to all of you anyway.